# ERROR: unable to find git executable in PATH/PATHEXT

Tags: python, git, guardian

My company asked us to install git guardian for security reason and as a part of installation I happened to do the following:

1. Added the API key in the envionmental variables
2. Added the `pre-commit-config.yaml` file in my root directory
   [C:\Users\umasravanthi.k01]
3. Installed Python and added its path in the env variables.
4. Ran: `pip install ggshield; pip install pre-commit`; and while
   running `ggshield install --mode global` this command in cmd I'm
   getting this **Error: unable to find git executable in
   PATH/PATHEXT**

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

[`ggshield`](https://www.gitguardian.com/ggshield) ([`GitGuardian/ggshield`](https://github.com/GitGuardian/ggshield#installation)) includes a [PR (432)](https://github.com/GitGuardian/ggshield/pull/432) which shows it executes `git` commands based on the OS PATH.

So double-check your `%PATH%` environment variable: `C:\Program files\Git\bin` should be in it before you start executing `pip install pre-commit`.